# XmlReader en C# me da un problema al cargar más de 2048 bytes

Tags: c#, sql, xml

Tengo problemas en la siguiente función:

```
public XmlReader lineasfactura(string codigo)
{
    XmlReader Resultado;
    SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection();
    try
    {
         SqlCon = Conexion.getInstancia().CrearConexion();
         SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand("lineas_factura", SqlCon);
         Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         Comando.Parameters.Add("@codigo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = codigo;
         SqlCon.Open();
         IAsyncResult result = Comando.BeginExecuteXmlReader();
                while (result.IsCompleted)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                Resultado = Comando.EndExecuteXmlReader(result);
                return Resultado;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (SqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Open) SqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

Recojo el XML de una consulta de Sql Server y si la consulta devuelve menos de 2048 caracteres lo hace bien, pero al intentar recoger consultas mayores me salta una excepción porque no termina de cargar todo el resultado y no se cierran bien los elementos.
He probado con XDocument y me dice que no es un formato correcto.
He leído desde un fichero y no tengo el mismo problema porque lo lee entero. Pero al hacerlo desde la consulta de Sql desde C# con Un SqlCommand y un XmlReader no lee todo y da error.
Incluso he usado la siguiente estructura:

```
IAsyncResult result = Comando.BeginExecuteXmlReader();
while (result.IsCompleted)
      {
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
      }
Resultado = Comando.EndExecuteXmlReader(result);
```

Que espera a que se ejecute por completo la consulta antes de cargar el Reader, pero ni aún así he conseguido que funcione.